# proving an operator is continuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

If $X$ is a topological vector space, and $X^*$ is the space of all continuous linear functionals $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$. Define the operator

$T:X^* \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^X=\prod_{x \in X}\mathbb{F}$

$T(f)=(f(x))_{x\in X}$
We need to show that

1. $T$ is bounded linear injective. I was able to prove the linearity and injection but not sure how to show it is bounded (or continuous) operator. I am not even sure how the norm of the range looks like.

Here, we define the weak topology on $X^*$ which has a base of neighborhoods at zeros of the form

$W(x_1,...,x_n;r)=\{f \in X^*: |f(x_i) < r, 1 \leq i 
\leq n \}$

2. Describe the open sets in $\mathbb{F}^X=\prod_{x \in X}\mathbb{F}$

Is it true that the open sets are of the form $\prod_{x\in X}U_x$ where $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: The description of open sets in $\prod\limits_{x \in X} \mathbb{F}$ is important, and it is not $\prod\limits_{x \in X} U_x$, where $U_x$ is an open set in $\mathbb{F}$. If at all we have such a description, we will require all but finitely many $U_x$'s to be $\mathbb{F}$ (that is the definition of product topology). Also, it seems that $T$ is the inclusion map.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I think the open sets are union of sets of the form $\prod_{x\in X} U_x$, right?

Comment: So ${\Bbb F}^X$ has the product topology and $T$ is continuous w.r.t. it?

Comment: @Adam_math, if you take $\prod\limits_{x \in X} U_x$ where $U_x$ is open in $\mathbb{F}$, then it is not the product topology. It is called the box topology (because you have created "boxes" by taking products of open sets). In product topology, we have a similar characterization but the only difference is that only finitely many $U_x$'s can be proper open sets. All others must be $\mathbb{F}$. The reason behind this is this definition gives the smallest topology in which projections are continuous, whereas as you can easily see, the box topology can be strictly larger.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I see. Thank you for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product topology on $\Bbb F^X$ is the minimal topology such that all maps $\pi_x: \Bbb F^X \to \Bbb F$, where $\pi_x(g)= g(x)$ for all $g$, are continuous, and has the universal property that $F : Y \to \Bbb F^X$ is continuous (for an arbitrary space $Y$ and function $F$) iff for all $x \in X$ we have $\pi_x \circ F$ continuous. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) e.g.

Applying it to the present case: $(\pi_x \circ T)^{-1}[U] = \{f \in F^\ast\mid f(x) \in U\}$ where $U \subseteq \Bbb F$ is open (an open disk in $\Bbb C$ or an open interval in $\Bbb R$). The right hand side is just a shifted version of some $W(x; r)$, essentially (if we take $U$ to be $r$-balls, which is sufficient for continuity), and so all $\pi \circ T$ are continuous and so is $T$.

The map $T$ is in fact the "identity" in disguise, and the weak-star topology a relative version of the product topology.

Comment: thank you for the clarifications.